# More complicated ways of solving a problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Feynman says the following,

> we shall first study the equation,
>   $$d^2x/dt^2 = -x$$
>   [...] We assume that in the meantime the Mathematics Department has brought forth a function
>   which, when differentiated twice, is equal to itself with a minus sign. (There are, of
>   course, ways of getting at this function in a direct fashion, but they are more complicated > than already knowing what the answer is.) The function is $x= \cos t$.

What are these more complicated fashions and where can I learn more about them?

Comment: maybe the author thinks of performing a Picard/Euler-iteration and  deduce the function by its power series representation. Or you could consider it as a linear equation and use the connection to the characteristic polynomial.

Comment: Assume $x(t) = \sum_{k \ge 0} a_k t^k$, plug into the equation, get a recurrence for the $a_k$, solve it, aha!

Comment: Try $x(t) = a e^{b t}$, plug into the equation and see what comes out. Try to solve for $a$ and $b$.

Comment: (Don't take random famous scientists too seriously... Feynman is justly famous for playing all sorts of pranks)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What are these more complicated fashions?

Incomplete list, partly based on comments:

1. Solve $x''+x=0$ by forming the characteristic equation $\lambda^2+1=0$, finding $\lambda=\pm i$, then massaging $x=c_1 e^{i t}+c_2e^{-it}$ into the more digestable form $x=a\cos t+b\sin t$
2. Laplace-transform $x''+x=0$ into $s^2 X+X = as+b$ where $a,b$ come from initial conditions at $t=0$. Solve: $X=\dfrac{as}{s^2+1}+\dfrac{b}{s^2+1}$. Invert the Laplace transform:  $x=a\cos t+b\sin t$.
3. Look for solution in the form of a power series $x=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n t^n$. When plugged into the equation, this will yield $n(n-1)a_n+a_{n-2}=0$ for $n\ge 2$. This will allow you to write down the entire series in terms of the first two coefficiets $a_0,a_1$. (It helps to change the notation by letting $b_n=n!a_n$.)
4. Rewrite the equation in the integral form $x(t)=a+bt-\int_0^t (t-s)x(s)\,ds$, where $a,b$ correspond to the initial conditions. Then run the Picard iteration starting from $x_0(t)=0$. This gives $x_1(t)=a+bt$, $x_2(t)=a+bt-\frac{a}{2}t^2-\frac{b}{6}t^3$, and so on... the result will be the same power series as in method 3.

> and where can I learn more about them?

In any book on ordinary differential equations, such as the [free textbook](http://www.jirka.org/diffyqs/) by  Jiří Lebl.